# How to find percentage for a given set of numbers?

Tags: percentages

If I have a set of numbers known in advance, how do I know which percentage is each number. What is the mathematical equation to do that?

For example, if I know I have the numbers 1,2,3,4,5. I know that 1 is 20%, 2 is 40%, 3 is 60%, 4 is 80% and 5 is 100%, but I don't know how to write the formula to get that percentage.

I'm in an excel file, where in cells I have 1,2,3,4,5 and I need to write down a percentage based on these numbers, but I don't know how to do that, and I don't want to do IF(1) then 20%.

Comment: $$100\%\cdot\frac{\text{num}}{\text{total num}}$$

Comment: This is not clear.  Do you know at least one of the percentages in advance?  For instance, do you know that the biggest one is $100\%$?

Comment: Percentage of what?  The greatest number?  You already seem to know how to do that.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I’m going to assume that you have a list $\{1, 2,3, ..., n\}$

Then the percentage corresponding to a number $k$ is given by $\frac{k \times 100}{n}$